# Approaching a teacher outside institution for MS thesis guide

Tags: research-process, thesis, advisor, masters, supervision

My institution allows me to pursue MS Thesis with a teacher from any other institute, I have interest in a topic and want to do my thesis in that. There are  many researchers in different institutes who work in that topic.

My questions are:

1. How do I approach a teacher in a different institute regarding this. How to make someone help me with my MS thesis and ask them to be the guide when we are not even in the same institute?
2. The topic I am interested in is quite vast. I am interested in certain aspects of it, each aspect being an independent research area. But I am also open to other aspects in the field which the professor might be working in. I am not sure which aspect to pursue, I can suggest some, but the teacher might not be interested in it. So how do I ask them to not only just be my mentor but also suggest and take my input and my interests in that field?

For example: Suppose  a field A has subtopics X , Y , Z and each somewhat related to each other. I am interested to explore Y and have some experience in Z. But I also like X.
Overall I like the field A.
I find a professor working in field A, and I suggest them to guide me for topic Y, but they say that they are currently working in X and I can work in X too. But then it may appear that I am not clear about what I need to do.

So how do I approach them so that I can get them to my guide but also listen to what I am interested in, and in the end we can come to a middle ground. I also want them to suggest some topics which could be interesting for research in the field and they are willing to do it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I approach a teacher in a different institute?

It seems unlikely that you could meet with this teacher in person (even not during a pandemic) because they are in a different location. While phone calls are time-efficient, email is generally a good approach for those whom you do not know on a personal basis because it is non-invasive and allows the teacher to reference back to content.

> How to make someone help me with my MS thesis?

You cannot make someone help you, especially not someone who is not bound by your university's rules and regulations. Since they are under no obligation to help, the teacher must *want* to help. If your research is interesting and the teacher is not too busy, you have a good chance.

> How to ask them to be the guide when we are not even in the same institute?

Send a polite and concise email to introduce yourself and your work. Making it clear why you want to work with this professor in particular is a good idea. Asking them to mentor you before they have gotten a chance to know you might be tricky. Instead, considering how you want this professor to help you (and deciding if *you* want to work with *them*) and building rapport with them might be helpful.

> The topic I am interested in is quite vast. I am interested in certain aspects of it, each aspect being an independent research area. But I am also open to other aspects in the field which the professor might be working in.

Being honest about your ideas and areas in which you are interested is a good idea. It might be helpful to think about why you are interested in certain topics as a way to have a clearer focus. Formulating learning goals might help in this endeavor.

> So how do I ask them to not only just be my mentor but also suggest and take my input and my interests in that field?

Building a relationship with this person is crucial to the mentor-mentee relationship. You cannot force someone to like or implement your ideas; however, reaching out to the professor and learning from them about particular topics will get you started on a good path.